# Можно ли узнать границы отрисовки View до отрисовки?

Tags: android, view

Когда составляется `layout` мы добавляем параметры. В случае если параметры `layout_width` и `layout_height` определены в числах - проблем с определением границ `View` нет. Вопрос в том, можно ли получить координаты (размеры) области в которой будет отрисовываться `View`? Если рассматривать конкретный пример:

Есть `layout`, у которого `padding` задается конкретным значением, пусть будет 8dp. Внутри него есть `View` у которого `width` и `height` определены как `match_parent`. Следовательно область в которой будет отрисована `View` известна приложению перед его отрисовкой, она будет равна `screenWidth - 2 * screenDpSize * 8` на `screenHeight - 2 * screenDpSize * 8`. Каким либо образом можно в рантайме получить числовые значения границ этой области ДО того, как `View` будет отрисовано?

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо создать собственный `View` и переопределить в нём метод `onMeasure()`, который вызывается перед отрисовкой `view`. Собственно этот метод получает расчётные размеры и устанавливает новые, если необходимо.

Comment: это понятно, но эти параметры приходят туда во время отрисовки, а я говорю о получении этих параметров до. То есть даже абстрагируясь от этого view, зная что он есть в разметке вытащить из него размеры его области отрисовки

Comment: тогда кастомный Layout и переписывать onLayout(), а в нём уже искать чайлдов